# Different behavior in a job when execute it from the kitchen

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration 7.1 to copy some local files to a Hadoop 2.8.0 Cluster. I have created a Hadoop Cluster connection on Pentaho and I'm using a Hadoop Copy Files step. I can successfully upload the files when I execute my job from the GUI (spoon.sh), I can see the following line on the log:

`Hadoop Copy Files - Processing row source File/folder source : [file:///home/etl/Desktop/users_full_20170620.csv] ... destination file/folder : [hdfs://hadoop:***@spark-master.cu:9000/value_iq]... wildcard : [null]`

But when I attempt to run the same transformation using the kitchen.sh fails I got the following error:

`Hadoop Copy Files - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Folder  file:///value_iq/bin/kettle/data-integration_7.1/hdfs:/hadoop:hadoop@spark-master.cu:9000/value_iq does not exist!`

Somehow it's adding the path where the kitchen.sh is located in front of the hdfs url, assuming that the destinations enviroment is local.

This is a screenshot of my Hadoop Copy Files step

[image: This is a screenshot of my Hadoop Copy Files step]

**a JIRA report of this bug has been created**: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16443

Answer (score 0):

It`s an issue with UI dependency. Submit jira case please on  http://jira.pentaho.com

Comment: Also seems like  firstly you try to copy with incorrectly configured hadoop cluster. 
So please check if you have folder with name "hdfs:" under file:///value_iq/bin/kettle/data-integration_7.1/ 

If it exists delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see PDI expects a file which does not exists. Create it!

To move a PDI solution from dev to prod, makes files references relative. Instead of hard-coding the folder name, press `Ctrl-space`, and select `${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}` which will be replaced at runtime by the name of the directory containing your job/transfo and are different on your dev machine and your prod environment.

You can setup manually these name before each un: you are presented a list of Parameters and Variables, among which the `{Internal.Job.Filename.Directory` which you can change for this run.

You can also (I advise you to do so early in the dev process) define your own variables. In the top menu, `Edit the kettle.properties`, and add `my-dir`. It will appear on the `Ctrl-space` and the `run options`. The kettle.properties is stored in a hidden directory named `.kettle`, and is different on your dev machine and your prod serer.

You will very soon how to set and change these variables in job and transfos with `Get variables` and `Set variable` in order to automate load with loops. SOme example can be found in the `sample` directory which was shipped with your PDI distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I'm aware about those production details, but the problem here is different, as you can see, kettle is adding a local path to a Hadoop URL (file:///value_iq/bin/kettle/data-integration_7.1/hdfs:/hadoop:hadoop@spark-master.cu:9000/value_iq)who is independent of the local system since exist in a remote cluster. And is not expecting a file since the error is related with the destination who is a folder.

Comment: Then, my answer is as @Sedos

Comment: The my avise is te same as [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006572/sedos](Sedos), Rise the case to Jira.